# Angular 2. How to detect if component is currently in viewport

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, dom, typescript

I'd like to detect if the component position. Is currently in a view port and if yes run the trigger which stats an animation on this particular component.

I can't find any "angular" way to do it.

Example app( main component) every div is a separate component of app:

```
<div id="one">ww</div>
<div id="two">aa</div>
<div id="three">rr</div>
<div id="four">asf</div>
<div id="five">Something...</div>
<div id="six">rq</div>
```

So... I'd like to detect when component five is in viewport (present on a screen) and start animate that component.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to start animation when component is fully initialised. I'd like to start animation when this component appear in a viewport. E.i. you scroll website and if component which initially was out of viewport appear in a viewport

Answer (score 11):

You could use the [ng-in-viewport](https://github.com/k3nsei/ng-in-viewport) plugin.

HTML:

```
<div id="five" in-viewport (inViewportAction)="action($event)">Something...</div>
```

Component:

```
action(event : any){
    if(event.value){
       //Do something here (e.g apply CSS class to start the animation)
    }
}
```

Check my detailed answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46973683/3014458).