# angular 2 play css animation when div/component is in viewport

Tags: html, css, angular

I am building a landing page with angular and in my third div from top I have some animations. First div occupies 100vh viewspace, another say 50 and then I have following div (all these divs represent individual components):

```
<div id="about" class="app-about-us-div-container">

    <div class="onboarding-flow mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div class="circle circle-1">
            <i class="onboarding-icon material-icons">local_phone</i>
            </div>
            <div class="onboarding-text">
                <p>Tell us your problem domain and we will customize our solution to meet your specific needs</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div class="circle circle-2">
                <i class="onboarding-icon material-icons">group</i>
            </div>
            <div class="onboarding-text">
                <p>Engage your project stakeholders, end users without any time hassle to build together a clear product vision</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
            <div class="circle circle-3">
                <i class="onboarding-icon material-icons">trending_up</i>
            </div>
            <div class="onboarding-text">
                <p>Benefit from our analytics to understand your users and their vision for the product. Build Personas to take best design decisions and streamline important product features </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It's css:

```
.app-about-us-div-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 70vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
}

.app-about-us-div-container h4{
    margin-top: 0%;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.onboarding-flow {
    align-content: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 75px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #cccccc;
    animation-name: pop;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    color: #cccccc;
}
.circle-1 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.circle-2 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.circle-3 {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}

.onboarding-icon {
    align-self: center;
    font-size: 65px;
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50% - 35px);
}

.onboarding-text {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 2%;
    width: 60%;
    left: 20%;
}
.onboarding-text p {
    font-size: 17px;
}

@keyframes pop {
    0% {
        color: #F44336;
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #F44336;
        background-color: #F44336;
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #EF5350;
        background-color: #EF5350;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is animations are played on pageload and till the user reaches to this div it's over. How can I make sure that these animations are played when this div is in viewport or at the top of the screen (I am not sure what could be the best option as the div above occupies 50vh so at one point both of them are visible 50 50)? Is anular animation of any help in this case?

It's component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-about-us',
  templateUrl: './about-us.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about-us.component.css']
})
export class AboutUsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used [ng-in-viewport](https://github.com/k3nsei/ng-in-viewport) to achieve something similar to this. Follow the instructions available on the plugin's GitHub page:

**1. Install the plugin**

```
    npm install --save ng-in-viewport intersection-observer
```

Note:  `intersection-observer` is a polyfill used to support all major browsers

**2. Usage Example**

In your module:

`import { InViewportModule } from 'ng-in-viewport';`

`import 'intersection-observer';`

In your template:

```
<div in-viewport (inViewportAction)="action($event)" class="circle circle-1">
      <i class="onboarding-icon material-icons">local_phone</i>
</div>
```

In your component:

```
action(event : any) {
        //do something with the element
}
```

You could for example use [Angular's Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to add a css class to the element:

```
import {Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
action(event : any) {
    if(event.value){ //if element is in viewport
      this.renderer.addClass(event.target, "circle-1");
    }
}
```

Comment: IntersectionObserverEntry is not supported in IE at all. Is there another way of doing this while supporting IE? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It will work you have to add one polyfill for it "import 'intersection-observer'; " in yout polyfill.ts @let_the_coding_begin

Comment: One caveat with regards to the polyfill and IE11 - the performance is often really bad. I wouldn't put that on this plugin, it's just that IE11 scripting is slow and the polyfill has to do a lot of work. But in our app, it literally just crashes the page, even when trying debouncing and other things.